# ZF2 + Doctrine 2 : Cli Tool has Access Denied

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a ZF2 2.1.3 app with Doctrine 2.

I installed using composer:

```
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*"
    ,"doctrine/doctrine-orm-module":       "dev-master"
```

A create a file `config/autoload/database.local.php` with the following:

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            // Default connection name
            'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'dbname'   => 'zf2-experimental',
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

I create my entity `Bar` under `Foo` module (`src/Business/Entity/Bar.php`) and configure it on `module.config.php` like this:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Business/Entity'),
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Business\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Ok! It's exactly at [Sam says here](http://samminds.com/2012/07/install-doctrine-2-for-zend-framework-2/)!

Then I create a simple `Foo` entity and run the doctrine cli tool:

```
c:\wamp\www\zf2-Experimental>.\vendor\bin\doctrine-module.bat orm:validate-schema
    [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.

      [PDOException]
      SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

    orm:validate-schema
c:\wamp\www\zf2-Experimental>
```

Looks like the cli tool can get my connection parameters in my `config/autoload/database.local.php`!

On Application index I tested my config:

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($config['doctrine']['connection']['orm_default']);
```

And this returned:

```
array (size=4)
  'configuration' => string 'orm_default' (length=11)
  'eventmanager' => string 'orm_default' (length=11)
  'params' => 
    array (size=5)
      'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
      'port' => string '3306' (length=4)
      'user' => string 'root' (length=4)
      'password' => string '' (length=0)
      'dbname' => string 'zf2-experimental' (length=16)
  'driverClass' => string 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' (length=36)
```

Someone can, please, help me?! :)
Thanks you all!

Comment: Since mapping files are validated, the error is definitely within the connection parameters. Are you absolutely sure your `root` has no password and the `dbname` is correct? :S

Comment: Hey @Sam! I found the answer! Can you please read and explain to me why this happens? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I waste a lot of time trying to solve this and finally did.

I forgot to mention that I using ZF1 environment-specific configurations style!
You can see [here](http://blog.evan.pro/environment-specific-configuration-in-zend-framework-2)!

I create my database config file in the following structure (I didn't mention this before, because I thought It wouldn't interfere on the question):

```
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'config_glob_paths'    => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        // Here! My config path is config/autoload/app_env/development/
        'config/autoload/app_env/' . (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?: 'production') . '{,*.}.local.php',
    ),
```

So, my database configs actually are in `config/autoload/app_env/development/database.local.php`!

When I copy-paste the file to `config/autoload/database.local.php` my CLI Tool works!

But WHY? Why the Cli Tool can't look for the config file inside another directory?
There is a way to work with sub-folders?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know internals, i would suggest you ping @Ocramius in #doctrine about this webchat.freenode.net or anyone else in there. They have more knowledge than me. To my understanding all configuration under `autoload` should be loaded. Maybe not recursively and only toplevel. No clue, honestly